# Java ExecutorService Implementation Assistance

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, executorservice

In the following code, `userList` gets high volume of data due to which sending email takes too long time.

How can I speed up the application such that 50000 emails are sent faster?  Maybe with the use of an `ExecutorService`?

```
List<String[]> userList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
void getRecords() {
    String [] props=null;
    while (rs.next()) {
    props = new String[2];
    props[0] = rs.getString("useremail");
    props[1] = rs.getString("active");
    userList.add(props);
    if (userList.size()>0) sendEmail();   
}
void sendEmail() {
    String [] user=null;
    for (int k=0; k<userList.size(); k++) { 
        user = userList.get(k);
        userEmail = user[0];         
        //send email code
    }
}
```

Comment: an ExecutorService could help.  what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try parallelize your code in such way:

```
private final int THREADS_NUM = 20;

void sendEmail() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( THREADS_NUM );
    for ( String[] user : userList ) { 
        final String userEmail = user[0];         
        executor.submit( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendMailTo( userEmail );
            }
        } );
    }
    long timeout = ...
    TimeUnit timeunit = ...
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination( timeout, timeunit );
}

void sendMailTo( String userEmail ) {
// code for sending e-mail
}
```

Also, note, if you don't want to have a headache - method `sendMailTo` must be stateless.

Comment: Don't index a `List`! If the underlying implementation is a `LinkedList` the performance will be horrible! Also you should call `shutdown` before `awaitTermination`.

Comment: Oops, I've just copy-pasted part of method from question )) The main idea was in submitting new thread inside loop. P.S. fixed

Comment: @stemm, Thanks a lot. Don't we have to implement Runnable in the class?

Comment: @user1651714, Class with method 'sendEmail' don't have to implement `Runnable`. In my code - I've used anonymous class: `new Runnable{ public void run(){...} }` - in this case its enough. Just add in anonymous class to method `run()` logic, which you would like to be performed asynchronously ( in my example - invoking of method `sendMailTo(..)` )

Answer (score 0):

You could do such task using `ExecutorService` as follows:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous task");
        /* Add your logic here */
    }
});

executorService.shutdown();
```

#### INFO

- You can find it's java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).
- A more detailed tutorial about `ExecutorService` is available [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html).

Comment: @mtk  thanks a lot. I am trying to implement executorService.